# Typescript array map with JSON.stringify produces error

Tags: typescript

In Typescript, this snippet:

```
[].map(JSON.stringify);
```

Is producing this error:

> Argument of type '{ (value: any, replacer?: ((key: string, value: any) => any) | undefined, space?: string | number | undefined): string; (value: any, replacer?: (string | number)[] | null | undefined, space?: string | ... 1 more ... | undefined): string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: never, index: number, array: never[]) => string'.
>   Types of parameters 'replacer' and 'index' are incompatible.
>     Type 'number' is not assignable to type '((key: string, value: any) => any) | undefined'.

Which I don't think it should.

To me this looks like a Typescript bug but before I file an issue in GitHub can you check if I'm doing something wrong?

Typescript version: `3.0.3`

Comment: You can kind of see what the problem is in the error: `map` expects a function that takes a value, an optional index, and an optional array. You're passing it `stringify`, which expects a value, an optional `replacer` function, and an optional `string` or `number` for indentation. That's not a function that takes a value, an optional index, and an optional array. TypeScript matches the entire signature, not excluding the optional parts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature of `JSON.stringify` and the `Array.map`are not compatible due to the second parameter:

```
interface JSON {
    /**
      * Converts a JavaScript value to a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) string.
      * @param value A JavaScript value, usually an object or array, to be converted.
      * @param replacer A function that transforms the results.
      * @param space Adds indentation, white space, and line break characters to the return-value JSON text to make it easier to read.
      */
     stringify(value: any, replacer?: (key: string, value: any) => any, space?: string | number): string;
}

interface Array<U> {
    /**
      * Calls a defined callback function on each element of an array, and returns an array that contains the results.
      * @param callbackfn A function that accepts up to three arguments. The map method calls the callbackfn function one time for each element in the array.
      * @param thisArg An object to which the this keyword can refer in the callbackfn function. If thisArg is omitted, undefined is used as the this value.
      */
    map<U>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): U[];
}
```

Here you can see that `stringify` does not match `callbackfn` because the second arguments do not match.

But you can absolutely do `[].map(i => JSON.stringify(i))`

Answer (score 1):

That's not a bug, it's clearly telling you that the type for the second argument of `JSON.stringify` (which is the replacer function), doesn't match the expected second argument of type `number` (which is the index) of the map function.